# .pdf file which doesn't displayed by Acrobat Reader

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have an `.pdf` file which doesn't opened by **Acrobat Reader** but it opened well by **Chrome**  . That file looks like it converted from `.ppt` to `.pdf` format   .

This is the prompt message I get in the Adobe  -

[image]

I work with **Adobe Acrobat X Version 10.1.2** .

Does it possible to open it with any Adobe yet ?

Comment: Is it only one specific PDF you're having this trouble with, or many?

Comment: Only this specifuc PFD

Comment: Then it's probably corrupted in a way Reader doesn't like. Get the user to make it again.

Comment: Adobe Reader tries to automatically repair PDF files when it encounters a malformed one, so if it can't open the PDF then it is safe to say that it is severely corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only this specific PDF and not all pdfs in general - I doubt that it is acrobat at fault.  If you want to, you can try updating to the latest version (11 at the time of writing)

Alternatively, try Foxit or another pdf reader to get this pdf open.  Once opened, you can always print it back to a "proper" pdf using pdfcreator or similar.

Hope this helps